# Show that $a_n=\frac{n}{n-1}a_{n-1}-1$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi i want to show that the next sequence diverges

$a_n=\frac{n}{n-1}a_{n-1}-1$

I thought that i can write $\frac{n}{n-1}$ as $1+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ can be as small as i want. 
 So for big enough n:

$a_n=a_{n-1}-1+\epsilon a_{n-1}<a_{n-1}$

As far as i understand i have proven (i think) that the sequence decreases from a certain $n$ but i'm not sure how to prove it's unbounded! 
Any help will be thanked!

Comment: What is the initial value for $a$?

Comment: @user63534 Consider accepting one of the many answers below if you find any helpful. Also do the same for your old questions. You've accepted $0$ answers so far.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that $\displaystyle \lim _{n\to +\infty} a_n=\lim _{n\to +\infty} a_{n-1}$, if any of them exists.

Name the above limit $l$ (assuming, in order to get a contradiction, that it exists).

Now take the limit as $n\to +\infty$ in $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{n}{n-1}a_{n-1}-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a_n$ converges to $a$. Take the limits of both sides to get:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n-1} \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n-1} - 1
$$

Simplify to get $a = a - 1$. Thus we get $ 0 = -1$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

You're on a good track.

Now if the sequence were bounded below, it would converge to $a$.

What happens if you take the limit in the recurrence relation
$$
a_n=\frac{n}{n-1}a_{n-1}-1?
$$
Can you see a contradiction?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean *recursive formula*?

Comment: @GitGud Oh! So nobody says induction formula...Thanks! That was a word for word translation from another language...Always dangerous.

Comment: I don't think so. I googled it and didn't find anything with that name.

Comment: @GitGud I just googled, apparently word for word translation is correct. But literal translation is better. Thanks again.

Comment: [Recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) is the most common term, I think.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Ah! And I've kept avoiding recurrence all this time because I thought it sounded too frenchy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite the equation as 
$$
x= \bigg( \frac{n}{n-1} \bigg)x -1
$$
and solve for $x$ you get
$$
x=n-1
$$
so if you take the limit as $n \to \infty$ you get $\infty$, hence the series diverges.